# How do I get both a COUNT() and SUM() LEFT JOIN in Laravel Eloquent?

Tags: laravel, join, eloquent

I'm pretty new to joins so excuse me as I get my head round it! I'm trying to join 2 tables onto a `links` table.

One table is `clicks`. I want the SUM of any data in the `clicks.clicks` column where `link_id` matches. (ie 2 columns, One with 1 in the column and a second with 4 in the clicks column both for `link_id=1` would return 5)

And the second table is `suggestions` which I want the COUNT of any occurrence of `link_id` to be displayed (ie 4 rows where `link_id=1` would return 4)

I'm using eloquent with 2 left joins for this and have managed to get both working independently, however when I put both together, `clicks_sum` which is the name of my SUM join goes wildly high (Seeming as if the `suggestion_count` is interfering with what's going on there)

Here's my code so far for what I'm trying to achieve. I'm loading Link ID `2872719` just to test with. It should return 585 for `suggestion_count` and 4 for `clicks_sum` but I am getting totally different results than expected

```
use App\Models\Link;
use App\Models\Suggestion;

return Link::select(
  'links.id',
  DB::raw('SUM(clicks.clicks) AS click_sum'), 
  DB::raw('COUNT(suggestions.link_id) AS suggestion_count'),    
)
->leftJoin('clicks', 'clicks.link_id', '=', 'links.id')
->leftJoin('suggestions', 'suggestions.link_id', '=', 'links.id')

->where('links.id', 2872719)
->first();
```

Returned is the following:

```
App\Models\Link {#1278
  id: 2872719,
  click_sum: "2340", // Should be 4
  suggestion_count: 585, // The presence of this join appears to affect click_sum
}
```

Any ideas on where I am going wrong?

All my best!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than having two `leftJoin` instances in your eloquent query you need to combine the two joins together into one `leftJoin`.

```
return Link::select(
  'links.id',
  // get the count of suggestions for each link
  DB::raw('(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM suggestions WHERE suggestions.link_id = links.id) AS suggestion_count'),
  DB::raw('SUM(clicks.clicks) AS click_sum'), 
)
->leftJoin('clicks', 'clicks.link_id', '=', 'links.id', 'suggestions.link_id', '=', 'links.id')

->where('links.id', 2872719)
->groupBy('links.id')
->first();
```

This should give you the correct result as below:

```
 #original: array:3 [▼
    "id" => 2872719
    "suggestion_count" => 586
    "click_sum" => "4"
  ]
```

When performing two `leftJoin` as you were previously, the `click_sum` was being multiplied by the total count of suggestions leading to the inflated number being returned.

Comment: Absolute legend. Cheers!